# SVM overfitting in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am building digit recognition classification using SVM. I have 10000 data and I split them to training and test data with a ratio 7:3. I use linear kernel.

The results turn out that training accuracy is always 1 when change training example numbers, however the test accuracy is just around 0.9 ( I am expecting a much better accuracy, at least 0.95). I think the results indicates overfitting. However, I worked on the parameters, like C, gamma, ... they don't change the results very much.

Can anyone help me out with how to deal with overfitting in SVM? Thanks very much in advance for your time and help.

The following is my code:

```
from sklearn import svm, cross_validation
svc = svm.SVC(kernel = 'linear',C = 10000, gamma = 0.0, verbose=True).fit(sample_X,sample_y_1Num)

clf = svc

predict_y_train = clf.predict(sample_X)
predict_y_test = clf.predict(test_X)    
accuracy_train = clf.score(sample_X,sample_y_1Num) 
accuracy_test =  clf.score(test_X,test_y_1Num)  

#conduct cross-validation 

cv = cross_validation.ShuffleSplit(sample_y_1Num.size, n_iter=10,test_size=0.2, random_state=None)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf,sample_X,sample_y_1Num,cv = cv)
score_mean = mean(scores)
```

Comment: ``gamma`` is not a parameter of the linear kernel, and changing it will not alter your results. What range of ``C`` did you try? Also: how did you split your data into training and test set, and what is your cross-validation accuracy?

Comment: First of all, thank for your response. I tried C from 1 to 1000000. I split the training data and test data with a ratio 7:3. Cross-validation accuracy is similar to test accuracy.

Comment: If you think you are overfitting then try using smaller values of `C`, like `10^-3`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to reduce the overfitting is by adding more training observations.  Since your problem is digit recognition, it easy to synthetically generate more training data by slightly changing the observations in your original data set.  You can generate 4 new observations from each of your existing observations by shifting the digit images one pixel left, right, up, and down.  This will greatly increase the size of your training data set and should help the classifier learn to generalize, instead of learning the noise.